# Redis, Transactions and Throughput

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions, redis

Alright, it's been about 10 hours, and I still can't figure this out. Can someone please help? I am writing to both Redis and MongoDB each time my Node/Express API is called. However, when I query each database by the same key, Redis gradually starts to miss records over time. I can minimize this behavior by throttling the overall throughput (reducing # of ops I'm asking Redis to do). Here's the pseudo code:

```
function (req, res) {
  async.parallel {
    f {w:1 into MongoDB -- seems to be working fine}
    f {write to Redis -- seems to be miss-firing}
```

And here the Redis code:

```
var trx = 1; // transaction is 1:pending 0:complete
  async.whilst(function(){return trx;},
    function(callback){
      r.db.watch(key);
      r.db.hgetall(key, function(err, result){
      // update existing key
      if (result !== null) {
        update(key, result, req, function(err, result){
          if (err) {callback(err);}
            else if (result === null) {callback(null);}
            else {trx = 0; callback(null);}
          });
      }
      // new key
      else {
        newSeries(bin, req, function(err, result){
          if (err) {callback(err);}
          else if (result === null) {callback(null);}
          else {trx = 0; callback(null);}
        });
      }
    });
  }, function(err){if(err){callback(err);} else{callback(null);}}
 );
```

in the "update" and "newSeries" functions, I'm basically just doing a MULTI/EXEC to redis using the values from HGETALL, and returning the result (to ensure I didn't hit a race condition).

I am using Cluster with Node, so I have multiple threads executing at once to Redis.
Any thoughts would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I just needed a bit of sleep, and a bit more log-trolling to figure this out.

Basically, it was the async.each loop above my block of code. Because that runs in parallel, EXEC was sometimes called on a different key! So it would wipe out the WATCH on another key! So, I just needed to switch it to async.eachSeries - which ensures my single node-worker isn't "working" (WATCH'ing and EXEC'ing) multiple keys at once!

So, first critical lessons: first, any EXEC command from a connection with wipe out all WATCH commands (so be very careful with parallel or Async processing).

And second, be very, very careful with async.each, and always default to async.eachSeries! For me, async.each is conceptually very tough - and it can really screw up single-threaded processes (like Redis). This has cost me a lot of time and pain over the past year... beware!

Hope this helps someone out there.